# what does ":2" mean in set variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this line in my batch file `@SET %~1=%~$PATH_VARNAME:2`. I don't see what ":2" stands for

more details:

```
@SET PATH_VARNAME=!%~3! 
@IF NOT DEFINED PATH_VARNAME SET PATH_VARNAME=%PATH%

@SET %~1=%~$PATH_VARNAME:2
```

`%~1` and `%~3` are `ARGV` arguments. 
when I `ECHO` `%~1` after the last set it shows me `C:\Mycomuter\currentdir\example\interface\SET_LIB_PERL_GENE_CSV.bat`

`C:\Mycomuter\currentdir\example\interface\` is the first path in `%PATH%` environment variable and `SET_LIB_PERL_GENE_CSV.bat` is the second ARGV argument

what does this line `%~$PATH_VARNAME:2` means, does take the first path of PATH_VARNAME and concatenate it with the second argument of .bat file (`SET_LIB_PERL_GENE_CSV.bat`) ?

Best regards

Comment: if `set /?` doesn't answer your question please be more specific. Your code doesn't make sense in pure `cmd` (i.e. `$PATH_VARNAME` isn't `cmd`/`batch-file` syntax (looks more like PowerShell)

Comment: @Stephan PATH_VARNAME=%PATH%, and by the way the code execute normally I just don't see the meaning of ":2"

Comment: There is no meaning of `:2`, as the whole construct is meaningless. (yes, it executes, but it just sets a variable (name given by the first parameter to the batch file) to nothing. Can you show more code "around it" to give it some context?

Comment: @Stephan I update the question adding some details

Comment: @Stephan `:2` is always defined in a batch script (but never in command line context), regardless how many arguments are passed to the batch file (All argument numbers are *defined* here). The construct expands to nothing or to a full path, if `%2` contains a file in the search path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "path_varname=%~dp0"
call :test myvar "%~nx0"
echo(%myvar%
exit /b

:test
set "%~1=%~$PATH_VARNAME:2"
```

Search for `%~2` in `%PATH_VARNAME%` and set the value to `%~1`.

The example will search for `%~2` which is passed `%~nx0` (script name) in `%path_name%` (script directory) and assigns the value to `%~1` (`myvar`).

The result is displayed with `echo(%myvar%` which will be the full path to the script.

See `for /?` at the bottom that mentions:

> ```
> %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                environment variable and expands %I to the
>                fully qualified name of the first one found.
>                If the environment variable name is not
>                defined or the file is not found by the
>                search, then this modifier expands to the
>                empty string
> ```

`PATH` can be any valid variable with a path(s).

Comment: Thanks, I thought it take the first path in`PATH` and concatenate with the `%~2` but it search for the second arguments in all paths and return the full path include the second argument in the end

Answer (score 3):

#### Some more in depth informations:

The syntax `%~$PATH:I` is rarley used, but it has some unexpected behavior.

## Behavior in batch files

### Simple percent version `%~$PATHVARIABLE:<NUMBER>`

- Only the numbers 0-9 are allowed, else a syntax error is thrown
- It expands to nothing if the filename in  can't be found in any of the pathes in PATHVARIABLE
- The numbers 0-9 are ALWAYS defined, when they are not set they are empty and the expansion results into nothing
- As a side effect, the for-variable `$` can't be used with `~`:
  `FOR %%$ in (1) do echo %%~dp$` fails

myBatch.bat myBatch.bat myBatch

```
@echo off 
set myPathVar=.
echo #0 %~$myPathVar:0
echo #1 %~$myPathVar:1
echo #2 %~$myPathVar:2
echo #3 %~$myPathVar:3
echo #4 %~$myPathVar:*
```

Output:

```
#0 C:\Temp\myBatch.bat  
#1 C:\Temp\myBatch.bat  
#2  
#3
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~$myPathVar:*
```

#### FOR-variable version `%%~$PATHVARIABLE:<for-variable>`

- All variable names are allowed
- The expression is discarded and used literally, when the variable is not defined
- The numbers 0-9 are used only from the for-variables, not from script arguments

#### FOR-variable detection

This can be used for detection, if a FOR-variable is already used (All for-variables are stored in a global FOR-variable-store).

```
@echo off 

FOR %%X in (test) do call :func
exit /b

:func

for %%1 in (one) do (
    if "%%~$=undef=:1" =="" echo varaible-1 is defined
    if "%%~$=undef=:2" =="" echo varaible-2 is defined
    if "%%~$=undef=:X" =="" echo varaible-X is defined
    if "%%~$=undef=:Y" =="" echo varaible-Y is defined
)
```

This outputs, that `1` and `X` are defined.

In this test `=undef=` is used as variable that is always undefined, therefore there is no path to be searched and the expansion can only be empty.

#### Disappearing quotes

This can also be used for **disappearing quotes**, this are quotes that `quotes` the line, but doesn't appear in the output.

```
FOR %%# in (test) DO (
  echo %%~$="=:# Disappearing quote, supports &<>| without ^ escaping
)
```

#### Percent delimiter

`%%~$=undef=:X` can be used to separate percent signs and characters, useful to echo literals, like `%X`

```
FOR %%X in (TEST) DO (
    echo Output [percent][X] %%X -- fails, expands to TEST
    echo Output [percent][X] %%%%~$=undef=:XX
)
```

## Behavior in command line context

### Simple percent version `%~$PATHVARIABLE:<NUMBER>`

- Never works, because there is no valid NUMBER
- The expression always remains unchanged

### FOR-variable version `%~$PATHVARIABLE:<for-variable>`

- There is only one percent sign
- Works like in a batch file